# Jumping from one dimension (1D) to two dimensions (2D)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here is a sample data file

```
m = {{-10,3,1},{-7.5,12,3},{-1.5,5,2},{2,4,4},{3,7,4},{6,9,5},{7,1,5},
     {8,3,1},{9,12,2},{10,8,5}};
```

The first element of the list is a point on the x-axis, while the other two are integers for other information.

Now let's create a color code depending on the third integer element

```
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := Module[{s = m[[i, 3]]}, 
Which[s == 0, Black, s == 1, Darker[Green], s == 2, Red, s == 3, 
Blue, s == 4, Magenta, s == 5, Orange, s == 6, Cyan, s == 7, 
Brown]];
```

And let's plot the color points on the x-axis

```
data = Table[{PointSize[0.001], getColor[m, i], Point[{m[[i, 1]], 0}]},
       {i, 1, Length[m]}];
S0 = Graphics[data]
```

[image]

The above plot does not correspond to the sample data but to the actual data file. Nevertheless we see that the colors are hardly visible since all points lie on the x-axis.

I would like the following: Get some height. In particular, for every color point $x_0$ to create a vertical line at $x_0$ with the same color let's say from $y_{min} = -1$ up to $y_{max} = 1$.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `Line`? p.s. Which -> Switch will shorten your code here.

Comment: @Kuba You mean `data = Table[{Thickness[0.001], getColor[m, i], 
    Line[{{m[[i, 1]], -1}, {m[[i, 1]], 1}}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];` right? How can `Which` could be substituted with `Which`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    m = {{-10, 3, 1}, {-7.5, 12, 3}, {-1.5, 5, 2}, {2, 4, 4}, {3, 7, 4}, {6, 9, 5}, {7, 1, 5}, {8, 3, 1}, {9, 12, 2}, {10, 8, 5}};

    colors = {Black, Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Brown};

    data = Table[{colors[[m[[i, 3]]]], Line[{{m[[i, 1]], -1}, {m[[i, 1]], 1}}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];
    S0 = Graphics[data]
```

[image]

Or more compactly (you don't need `Table`):

```
    Graphics[{colors[[#[[3]]]], Line[{{#[[1]], -1}, {#[[1]], 1}}]} & /@ m]
```

EDIT for Jason B:

The graphic was made with the following additional options:

```
    Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRangePadding -> None
```

Comment: When I type in your code, I don't see a frame at all, same with OP's code - I just see a bunch of really small dots for his.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JasonB Nothing wrong at all! The plot I posted was created using more options like `Frame` etc.

Comment: @JasonB Sorry I added the options after I'd copied the code. See my edit.

Comment: When I use your code the results do not match. What you define `colors = {Black, Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Brown};` does black correspond to option 1 or 0?

Comment: Ah my bad, yeah I had assumed your colour values went from 1, not 0. Just change `colours[[#[[3]]]]` to `colours[[#[[3]]+1]]`

Comment: Now everything is OK!